# Transform .max/3ds/.Obj to .ply

Tags: 3d, blender, 3dsmax, sketching

I find a lot of format of 3D Models in internet.
Is there a way to convert .Obj + Textures /.3ds/.Max  to .Ply files with color information in every Node.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Natively max does not export to the .ply file format.
Otherwise, you could search around and see if someone has written a plugin to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a MaxScript [here](http://theorangeduck.com/page/3ds-max-ply-exporter) that will export to PLY format from 3DS Max, however it's pretty basic.  Good news is the file format is simple so shouldn't take much to fix any issues.